# How to keep lower triangle plus diagonal in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that looks like below:

```
diag <- rep("Free",5)
offdiag <- rep("0.0", 5*6/2 )
m <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(diag), nrow = length(diag))
m[lower.tri(m)] <- offdiag
m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(t(m))]
diag(m) <- diag
m
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
[1,] "Free" "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0" 
[2,] "0.0"  "Free" "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0" 
[3,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" "0.0"  "0.0" 
[4,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" "0.0" 
[5,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free"
```

I would like to keep the lower triangle plus the diagonal elements like below with adding a comma (`,`) after each value and `;` at the end. Is it possible to produce this below?

```
              Free, 
              0.0, Free, 
              0.0, 0.0, Free, 
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Free, 
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Free, 
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Free;
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `offdiag` length is different.  YOu can set the upper diagonal as `""` i.e. `m[upper.tri(m)] <- ""`

Comment: Regarding the expected output.  Is it a matrix output or string

Comment: Perhaps, you may need `apply(m, 1, function(x) toString(x[seq_len(match("Free", x))]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the rows, `paste` the elements up to 'Free', and then write it to a file with `cat`

```
cat(paste0(paste(apply(m, 1, function(x) 
    toString(x[seq_len(match("Free", x))])), 
          collapse=",\n"), ";"), file = 'file1.txt')
```

-output

[image]

---

Or extract the elements with `lower.tri` and do a group by `paste` with `tapply`

```
cat(paste0(paste(tapply(m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)], 
   row(m)[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)], FUN = toString), 
      collapse=",\n"), ";"), file = 'file1.txt')
```

#### data

```
m <- structure(c("Free", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "Free", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "Free", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "Free", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "Free"
), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How can I keep it as one string variable?

Comment: @amisos55 Just remove the `cat` at the end.  `cat` is used to write to the file or print to console if `file` is not specified